# FOSFacebookBundle does not work on my site

Tags: symfony, fosfacebookbundle

I try to use FOSFacebookBundle & FOSUserBundle.
It set up as the manual.
An error does not come out.

---

A user registration, login, logout of FOSUserBundle was success.
And invitation registration was added.

It is normal so far and I understand operation and processing.

---

And I try to add FOSFacebookBundle.
It set up as the manual.
An error does not come out.
Pop-up is displayed from a login button and login of facebook is successful.

I do not understand the action and processing after here.

---

If it has succeeded, is a user added to a database?

If it has succeeded, does "isGranted" work?

```
if ( $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ) {
    // ...
}
```

---

So, facebook login is successful from my site.
However, on my site, it does not have influence of what.
The login state via Facebook cannot be handled.

There is no error.
How do I handle a user in a controller?
Where should be checked?
Since an error is not displayed, there is no telling where a problem should be investigated from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your database ? Normally you should have a new user with a ROLE_FACEBOOK.
If you can understand french, you should take a look [here](http://devyourdream.net/2012/10/06/fosfacebookbundle-fosuserbundle-installation-et-configuration-pas-a-pas/).

Comment: If logged in by Facebook, does it register with a database automatically?   
My database (FOSUser) did not have change.   
Although there is no error, there is a mistake in somewhere.   
I check from a configuration file.